# Copy, Name and Paste Table n Times

Tags: vba, excel

I have a single-column table, called Table1, beginning in A1 of Sheet1. I want to create n copies of Table1, name each successive copy as a defined name in Excel (Table2, Table3,... Tablen), and place these copies in col B, C, etc, of Sheet1. Code:

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste_Table1_n_times(n As Integer)

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To n
        Range("Table1").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i + 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="Table" & (i + 1), _
        RefersTo:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, i + 1),Cells(10, i + 1))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How can you just have a table in just A:1? If you create a column in A:1 it automatically creates one from A:1 to A:2

Comment: Updated question to clarify

Comment: I am working on it. Almost done

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score -1):

Answered my own question. The code is updated and it works. the trick was finding the right syntax to generate the defined names:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="Table" & (i + 1), _
RefersTo:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, i + 1),Cells(10, i + 1))
```

Comment: If you look at name manager though, using this route you only create another label and not another table